# Finding variance/mean/std given random variable/probabilities in Python

Tags: python, numpy, math, statistics

How do I find the variance/mean/std given the random variable/probabilities using python, for example:

Chance of event 1: 0.124,
Chance of event 2: 0.375,
Chance of an event 3: 0.375,
Chance of event 4: 0.125

Answer (score 0):

This is what we call in [OpenTURNS](http://openturns.org) a UserDefined distribution

```
import openturns as ot

distribution = ot.UserDefined([[1],[2],[3],[4]], [0.125,0.375,0.375,0.125])
```

First argument is the list of events while the second argument is the list of weights. The sum of weights = 1. If not, they are automatically normalized.

You have automatically access to the mean `distribution.getMean()[0]` (= 2.5) and the standard deviation `distribution.getStandardDeviation()[0]`  (= 0.8660254037844386)

But you can also easily plot the PDF and CDF of the distribution

In your case, `distribution.drawPDF()` gives
[image]

and  `distribution.drawCDF()` gives
[image]